# Issues with pointer-events and z-index

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I've been tearing my hair out for a while now trying to figure out why I can't click the links in my footer. I know my css is a bit sloppy,  but it gets the job done. There's probably a lot more efficient way to get the effect of a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page that appears *behind* all the rest of my content, but this is what I have so far:

[here's my jsfiddle of my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/auFeV/2/)

it looks a bit messed up in the jsfiddle, but the idea is thereI have a pointer-event:none here:

```
.bottomdivtransparent {
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Which *should* make it so I can click the links, but they remain unclickable! I'm sure the error is something really simple and staring me right in the face..

Any suggestions? Or any easier way to get the footer to appear behind all of my content but still extend about ~300px below everything?

Thank you!

edit: Thanks to [Kasyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430754/kasyx) and [Andrea Ligios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654265/andrea-ligios) for the help -- they have determined that it works fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome for some reason. The margin-bottom property is messing up on .bottomdiv..

Comment: `pointer-events` will work only for nested elements. And you have `.bottomdivtransparent` and `.footer` on same DOM level.

Comment: thank you for the response! I will have to think of another solution to getting stuff to appear behind my content then I think..

Comment: I've found solution for you, check answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i noticed in comment `pointer-events` will not work in this case. But instead of it ill suggesting you to add `margin-bottom` to your div like in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auFeV/6/

```
.bottomdiv {
    //(...)
    margin-bottom: 310px;
    //(...)
}
```

(Thank you @Andrea Ligios for improving this answer)

Comment: Just tried this, it increases the .bottomdiv by the size I want for the footer but when I remove the .bottomdivtransparent the .bottomdiv goes to the end of the page, not allowing me to see the footer :(

Comment: Have you check my fiddle? It works there. Footer is visible when you scroll down whole text.

Comment: Yeah I checked the fiddle, this is what I see on mine if I scroll down all the way: [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/ASXLhkl.png)

Comment: here is what it should look like (except the links would work!) if I wasn't clear! [imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/2rOojOg.png). The page is all the way scrolled down, and the footer appears behind the white div above it ^^

Comment: So it depends on browser then. Im using newest Firefox, and it looks like on your second screen. :) What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome! Hmmm I did not think that chrome would have an issue like this! Yeah I just opened it in Firefox, looks perfect! Damn, no idea what would be making Chrome do this hmmm

Comment: This is the solution. Please correct your CSS: remove `.body` (it should be `body`, but you don't want it), remove `z-index: -3` from `html` (useless to apply it to html, and not working because `z-index` works only with non-`static` `position`s); then, `text-transformation` is `text-transform`, `weight` is `font-weight`, etc. It is possible that your browser is not working like expected because of this errors too... P.S: there is no need to include <body> in jsFiddle. Start from this: http://jsfiddle.net/auFeV/6/

Comment: thank you for the feedback! I fixed those things you mentioned and it still won't work in chrome, but it works perfectly in firefox.. so strange

Comment: I was able to get it to show the footer by adding a container div with overflow: auto in it around my entire page, but I still can't click on the links :( gah so frustrating

Comment: Ill try to think about another option for you then.

Comment: I figured out what was the issue -- you can't have negative z-index values wrapped around stuff in Chrome apparently. Just shifted all my z-index values up a point or two and everything works fine! Thank you for the help all!